# Is there a way to simplify $z_1z_2^n + \bar{z_1}\bar{z_2}^n$, for complex $z_k$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\bar{z_1}, \bar{z_2}$ their conjugates. Is there a way to simplify the expression

$$z_1\cdot(z_2)^n + \bar{z_1}\cdot(\bar{z_2})^n$$

or represent in a different form?

Comment: $\frac{5+2\sqrt{6}i}{2}\left( \frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} i \right)^n + \frac{5-2 \sqrt{6}i}{2} \left( -\frac{\sqrt{6}}{6} i \right)^n $

Comment: It is easy to find $i^n$ for any integer $n$...

Comment: I know but I have no idea how to use here

Comment: $(ai)^n=a^n\cdot i^n$

Comment: How about $2\Re[z_1z_2^n]$?

Answer (score 0):

It's well know that
$$
z\cdot\bar{z}=|z|^2.
$$

Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
z\cdot(\bar{z})^n+\bar{z}\cdot(z)^n &= z\cdot\bar{z}\cdot(\bar{z})^{n-1}  + \bar{z}\cdot z\cdot(z)^{n-1} \\
&=|z|^{2}\cdot\left((\bar{z})^{n-1} + z^{n-1} \right ) \\
& = |z|^{2}\cdot\left((|z|^2z^{-1})^{n-1} + z^{n-1} \right ) \\
& = |z|^{2}\cdot\left(|z|^{2(n-1)}z^{-n+1} + z^{n-1} \right ).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

In polar form, by De Moivre's formula, we have
$$
z^n=|z|^n(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)).
$$

So,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|z|^{2(n-1)}z^{-n+1}&= |z|^{2(n-1)} \left(|z|^{-n+1}(\cos((-n+1)\theta)+i\sin((-n+1)\theta)) \right) \\
&=|z|^{n-1}\left(\cos((-n+1)\theta)+i\sin((-n+1)\theta) \right),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and
$$
z^{n-1}=|z|^{n-1}(\cos((n-1)\theta)+i\sin((n-1)\theta)).
$$

Adding up and using the trigonometric formulas
\begin{align}
\cos(x)+\cos(y)&= \cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right),\\
\sin(x)+\sin(y)&=\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right),
\end{align}
we have that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|z|^{2(n-1)}z^{-n+1}+z^{n-1}&= |z|^{n-1}\left(\cos((-n+1)\theta)+i\sin((-n+1)\theta) \right. \\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\left.\cos((n-1)\theta)+i\sin((n-1)\theta) \right) \\
& =|z|^{n-1}\cos((-n+1)\theta).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Finally,
$$
z\cdot(\bar{z})^n+\bar{z}\cdot(z)^n=|z|^2|z|^{n-1}\cos((-n+1)\theta)=|z|^{n+1}\cos((-n+1)\theta),
$$
where $\tan(\theta)=b/a$ if $z=a+bi$.

Comment: I see that @Blue changed your question while I wrote this. Try a similar argument!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: $z=r(\cos\theta+i\cdot \sin \theta)=r\cdot e^{i\theta}$, where $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin \theta$

Step 2: $z^n=r^ne^{i\cdot n\theta}$

Step 3: $\left\{ \begin{matrix}z_1\cdot z^n_2&=&r_1r^n_2e^{i(\theta_1+n\theta_2)}&=&r_1r^n_2[\cos (\theta_1+n\theta 2)+i\sin(\theta_1+n\theta_2)]\\\bar{z_1}\cdot  \bar{z_2}^n&=&r_1r^n_2\frac{1}{e^{i(\theta_1+n\theta_2)}}&=&r_1r^n_2[\cos(\theta_1+n\theta_2)-i\sin(\theta_1+n\theta_2)]\end{matrix}\right.$

Step 4: revert to trigonometric form, the expression becomes
$$ z_1\cdot z^n_2+\bar{z_1}\cdot \bar{z_2}^n=2r_1r^n_2\cos{(\theta_1+n\theta_2)}(\therefore)$$